# Could using fewer antennae than a wireless NIC has connectors for cause any problems?

Tags: wireless-networking

Could damage to a radio occur?

Is there likely to be a performance impact?

If connecting one or two of a possible three antennae, will the choice of antenna ports used have any impact?

Answer (score 1):

Damage: certainly not.

Performance: yes. Best case is some loss of speed, for other devices with three antennas. For devices with one or two, maybe not. Worst case, maybe a big drop in speed.

Choice of ports: might matter. I can only say check the manual. See if the AP can be set to 802.11n with two antennas, 2x2 MIMO or something, and see which two they are.